# Javascript delete than splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, splice

I am working on javascript project where I have 2 arrays 1. elements 2. elementsOrder ; elementsOrder array contains the names of each element, and elements array contains all properties of each element. When I want to delete one element from each array I do it with "delete" build in function, but it doesn't deletes element only sets it to Undefined, so than I use splice method to push out those undefined elements, but it doesn't work.

the is the source:

```
var s1 = elementsOrder.indexOf(id);
delete elements[s1];
delete elementsOrder[s1];
```

it does the job and sets elements one by one "undefined" smoothly, but when I do:

```
var s1 = elementsOrder.indexOf(id);
delete elements[s1];
delete elementsOrder[s1];
elements.splice(s1, 1);
elementsOrder.splice(s1, 1);
```

using simply splice methods **don't** work:

```
var s1 = elementsOrder.indexOf(id);
elements.splice(s1, 1);
elementsOrder.splice(s1, 1);
```

I use this piece of code in my Javascript Canvas project to animate some canvas objects, so I can easily see when "delete" works smoothly and "undefines" elements one by one, and splice doesn't works so smoothly and doesn't puts out elements one by one

**Please see http://jsfiddle.net/7ZuuZ/ pay atantion to function animate, third function from bottom**

Comment: gives us a jsfiddle! it'll help answer accuracy and speed!

Comment: Why are you using delete? splice is sufficient enough to do what you want. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: Add expected and actual output!

Comment: `delete` *does* delete the property on the array, but as `Array` objects are still just objects, existing item indices don't automatically shift.

Comment: @phil I edited my post and you can see my jsfidle, please pay attantion to function animate it is third function from bottom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just splice in the first place?

```
var s1 = elementsOrder.indexOf(id);
elements.splice(s1,1);
elementsOrder.splice(s1,1);
```

There is no need to `delete` here.

Comment: I tried your way but it doesn't work, It is not such simple, please see http://jsfiddle.net/7ZuuZ/

Comment: Yes you are right, my problem was NOT the splice, I had another problem that I have allready solved, so thanks anyways